# SML recursively calling function

Tags: sml

I am trying to implement a recursively calling function in SML. My code is

```
CM.make "$cml/cml.cm";
open CML;
fun sender n()= if (n<100)
then 
(
TextIO.print (Int.toString(n)^"\n");
sender n+1
)
else
exit ()

fun main () = let
    val _ = spawn (sender 3);
    val tid1 = getTid();
in
    TextIO.print("MY TID" ^ (tidToString tid1)^"\n")
end;
RunCML.doit(main, NONE);
```

I am getting the below error

`Cml.sml:3.5-10.8 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [circularity]
  expression:  unit -> 'Z
  result type:  'Z
  in declaration:
    sender = (fn arg => (fn <pat> => <exp>))`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sender` starts with

```
fun sender n()= ...
```

which gives it the type

```
sender : int -> unit -> 'a
```

as you need for your definition in `main`.  However, when you later call it recursively, you call it as

```
sender n+1
```

Now, even if you write this as

```
sender (n+1)
```

to get the correct precedences, you still get the type `unit -> 'a` whereas you want the type `'a`.  So all you need to do is to pass an extra `() : unit` to it, and your `sender` function will typecheck:

```
fun sender n () =
    if (n<100)
    then (
        TextIO.print (Int.toString(n)^"\n");
        sender n+1 ())
    else exit ()
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, I have some doubts on the () operator in SML my code works if I remove that. and don't pass () while calling sender, so what's the point of having it in the code?

Comment: You could define `fun sender' n = ...`, and it would work nicely without the extra `()`, but later on you want to use `spawn` to spawn a thread that executes `sender` in parallel.  By design, `spawn` takes a `unit -> unit`, so you have to make your use of `sender'` conform to that.  You could do that via `spawn(fn () => sender' 3)`, of course.